# How to make the subfloat below and centered with the Figures

Tags: subfloats

I'm new to using Latex and I have a question. How to make the subfloat below and centered with the Figures? Follow the code and images of the assembly using 2 and 3 figures.

WITH 2 FIGURES

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \caption{Modelo físico de placa plana isotérmica imersa em domínio de ar em (a) vista isométrica e (b) vista superior.}
        \subfloat(a)
        {\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{Capitulo4/Figuras/placaplana1.png}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat(b) {\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{Capitulo4/Figuras/placaplana2.png}}
    \label{fig:placaplana1}
\legend{Fonte: Próprio Autor.}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

WITH 3 FIGURES

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \caption{Vistas (a) superior total, (b) superior com um quatro de domínio por dupla simetria em relação aos eixos y e z e (c) frontal, da placa corrugada e objeto de estudo desta tese.}
        \subfloat(a) {\includegraphics[width=0.46\columnwidth]{Capitulo4/Figuras/placacorrugada1.png}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat(b) {\includegraphics[width=0.44\columnwidth]{Capitulo4/Figuras/placacorrugada2.png}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat(c) {\includegraphics[width=0.95\columnwidth]{Capitulo4/Figuras/placacorrugada3.png}}
    \label{fig:modeloplacaretangular}
\legend{Fonte: Próprio Autor.}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

Attached images follow.

Thank you all for the attention.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and which package(s), if any, you load to create subfloats.

Comment: I don't know how to answer the question exactly. Documentclass article, I guess. No package (s)

Comment: Regarding "no packages I guess": If you don't load a package that defines `\subfloat`, your document can not compile. You will instead be left with error messages complaining about an undefined control sequence. Do you load the `subfig` or the  `subcaption` package in your actual document? If so, which of the packages do you use? Apart from that, `\legend` is not a standard command either. You must have added a package that defined `\legend` or used `\newcommand{\legend}...`  in your preamble. Please also add this information to your question.

Comment: BTW, for a single page of landscpae, [p] is better than [!h]., although since there is an automatic \clearpage before and after, the only difference is the spacing above and below.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of the `\subfloat` command you tried to use in your original code does not match the syntax that is edfined in the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package. Based on your comment  "No package (s) "  I assume, you actually did not include either `subfig` or `subcaption` in your document. Without one of the two packages, you should recieve  `Undefined control sequence.  \subfloat` upon trying to compile your document. Once you recuieve an error message, do not look at the output. Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error. Therefore, please don't ignore error messages but try to fixt them, before worrying about dapting the output.

The correct syntax of the `\subfloat` command is as follows:

```
\subfloat[<listentry>][<sub-caption>]{<body>}
```

`<listentry>` is optional and refers to the caption text that is added to the list of figures/tables

`<sub-caption>` is optional as well and refers to the caption text (not the number!) that is added with your image. If you want an output such as "(a) my subcaption text here", use `\subfloat[my subcaption text here]{<body>}`. If you just want to get an output such as "(a)", use `\subfloat[]{<body>}` with an empty optional argument.

`<body>` refers to the correpsonding image/tabular

In the following MWE, I have corrected the syntax of `\subfloat` according teh the above explanations. I have also used `\subfre` in order to refer to induvidual subfigures in the main caption. If you decide to rearrange the figures (e.g. swith subfigure a and b) there is no need to alter the main captions, as the letters will adapt automatically.

With `\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=bottom}` I made sure the subcaptions are placed below the corresponding images.

In the second example, I have slighlty altered the widths of the images and additionally slightly changes the spacing in order to allow for an improved horizonal alignment. The left edges of image a and c are now aligned, likewise the right edges of image b and c.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % do not use the demo option in your real document!
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=bottom}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \caption{Vistas (\subref{placacorrugada1}) superior total, (\subref{placacorrugada2}) superior com um quatro de domínio por dupla simetria em relação aos eixos y e z e (\subref{placacorrugada3}) frontal, da placa corrugada e objeto de estudo desta tese.}
    \label{fig:modeloplacaretangular}
        \subfloat[my subcaption text]{\includegraphics[width=0.46\columnwidth]{Capitulo4/Figuras/placacorrugada1.png}\label{placacorrugada1}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[my subcaption text]{\includegraphics[width=0.44\columnwidth]{Capitulo4/Figuras/placacorrugada2.png}\label{placacorrugada2}}
        
        \subfloat[my subcaption text]{\includegraphics[width=0.95\columnwidth]{Capitulo4/Figuras/placacorrugada3.png}\label{placacorrugada3}}
    
%\legend{Fonte: Próprio Autor.} % commented out because I don't know where/how it is defined in your original document.
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \caption{Vistas (\subref{placacorrugada1}) superior total, (\subref{placacorrugada2}) superior com um quatro de domínio por dupla simetria em relação aos eixos y e z e (\subref{placacorrugada3}) frontal, da placa corrugada e objeto de estudo desta tese.}
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{Capitulo4/Figuras/placacorrugada1.png}\label{placacorrugada1}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{Capitulo4/Figuras/placacorrugada2.png}\label{placacorrugada2}}
        
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Capitulo4/Figuras/placacorrugada3.png}\label{placacorrugada3}}
    \label{fig:modeloplacaretangular}
%\legend{Fonte: Próprio Autor.}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```